# Linux shell scripting floating point as argument

Tags: shell

how i can pass a floating point value to a shell script and make calculation in that number
i try bash countDown.sh 1/12
but it can't done correctly.
the script convert the argument from minute to seconds and then countdown

Comment: You'll need a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Most shells don't do floating-point arithmetic; `countDown.sh` is receiving the literal 4-character string `1/12` as an argument. You need an external program like `bc` to do floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: All we can do is guess at your problem. a MCVE is needed. That said, shell doesn't care what you pass it, `"gorilla", "123", "123.456"` are all the same to the shell. It's how you handle the argument within your script that counts. You can easily split the floating-point representation into real-part and fractional-part with parameter expansions and you can handle the floating point computations with `bc`, `calc` or `awk`.

Comment: Are you mistaking a rational number for a floating point number?

Answer (score 0):

I read your question as: I want to pass some fractional number of minutes to my script, convert that into seconds, and count down to zero:

```
seconds=$(echo "60 * $1" | bc)
for ((; seconds > 0; seconds --)); do 
    echo $seconds
    sleep 1
done
echo boom
```